# Eloquent Fatal error: Call to undefined method Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints() in \illuminate\database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 451

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRJakYFL538&index=17&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGGxaR6uFtwZnnbcXqyq8JD) where you can save relationships in one table to determine if a user is friend of another user and viceversa.

In my case, I need to save in a relational table `boundTogether_projects` those projects that are bound together.

So inside the Project.php Model I created the following Eloquent relationships:

```
<?php
    /*** Bound together projects ***/
    public function projectsBoundToThisOne(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Models\User\Project', 'boundTogether_projects', 'bound_id', 'project_id');
    }
    public function boundTo(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Models\User\Project', 'boundTogether_projects', 'project_id', 'bound_id');
    }
    public function boundTogetherProjects(){
        return $this->projectsBoundToThisOne()->wherePivot('bound',true)->get()->merge($this->boundTo()->wherePivot('bound', true)->get());
    }
```

This is not working, since I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints() in
>   \illuminate\database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 451

Looks like the problem comes right when I call this method as eager loading. That is to say:

```
$projects = Project::with('boundTogetherProjects');
```

The Eloquent version is 5.1

What am I missing? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because `boundTogetherProjects` is not relationship method. It simple gets some data from relationship merged to the other. So the valid way would be:

```
$projects = Project::with('projectsBoundToThisOne','boundTo');
```

and then for each project you could run `boundTogetherProjects` to get the projects

```
$projects->each(function($project) {
  dd($project->boundTogetherProjects());
});
```